# Cubic function and values between $0$ and $255$

Tags: cubics

For a computer vision program, I have values **between $0$ and $255$** that need to follow a **cubic function ($y=x^3$) behavior** so that :

- $f(255) = 255$
- $f(\frac{255}{2}) = 128$
- $f(0) = 0$

But I don't know how to find its equation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What you're asking is unclear. Could you clarify?

Comment: Is it so that the function has to be of the form
$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3
$$
? If not, what is the exact form that it has to follow? As you can see, simply $f(x) = x^3$ will not do and it needs some coefficients.

Comment: You need to have 4 points to uniquely determine a cubic polynomial

Comment: The quadratic $\frac {257}{255} x - \frac {2}{65025}x^2$ already works.  If you insist on a cubic you should add another point.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Here is the function I am aiwaiting :
https://imgur.com/uK6jwW6

Comment: If you have a graph you believe in you should be able to add a fourth point to your data.

Comment: Worth noting:  you can do this in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).  The syntax is "InterpolatingPolynomial[(0,0),(255,255),(255/2,128)]"  If you have a fourth point you just add it to the list.

Comment: I fear that if I add a 4th value, it would be too much estimated, like $f(64) ~= 115$

Comment: Dou you need the tangent to be horizontal in $(128,128)$?

Comment: @lulu, it seems that with your technics, I get a pretty good result with WolframAlpha : `InterpolatingPolynomial[(0,0),(255,255),(255/2,128),(64,115)]`.

The only problem is that it isn't exact.

Comment: If you add the point $(64,115)$  WA gives $\frac {3291827}{50473965600}x^3 - \frac {2521352551}{100947931200 }x^2+ \frac {1238395021}{395874240}x$

Comment: @zar, I need that $f(127) >= f(128) >= f(129)$.

Comment: Yes.  It shouldn't matter too much if your point is a little inaccurate but if you are worried about that, test it.  try the point $(64,100)$ instead.  And so on.  Convince yourself that you are close enough (or not).

Comment: Thank you @lulu, I will do like that. Post your answer as... answer, so I accept it !

Comment: Oh, it's just a WA calculation.  If you are so inclined post your own answer, maybe with some testing around the extra point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natural parameterIn addition to your own answer: a natural 4th condition is to fix the slope in the middle (that's the only thing you are allowing to change). This makes sense, because it defines the contrast of the nonlinear mapping. Using it this way, you can get through analytically.

Let's stretch everything to the unit square (divide $x$ and $y$ by $255$).

Start with a *centered* cubic curve (only odd terms allowed to keep the symmetry), it has one important parameter $a$ that sets the slope through the center:
$$y(x)=x^3+ax$$

Make it go through $(1,1)$:

$$y(x)=\frac{x^3+ax}{1+a}$$

Now it goes from (-1,-1) to (1,1) and is symmetric around the center. Squeeze it into the box from (0,0) to (1,1) by scaling by factor of 1/2 and shifting by 1/2 in both axes:

$$y(x)=\frac12+\frac12\left(\frac{(2x-1)^3+a(2x-1)}{1+a}\right)$$

$2x-1$ is there so that it maps 0 to -1 and 1 to 1.

This is already a final solution (replace $x$ by $x/255$ and multiply result by $255$ to go back to byte values). This shows that most ugly terms come from expanding the powers, but actually, the function is much more simple and this is also how you should compute it if you are using floating point numerics (if using integers/bytes, then you must expand).

For different values of $a$ it has different slopes, but all go through desired points. A special case $a=0$ which has horizontal tangent is also interesting. Negative values of $a$ don't produce unique mappings (not one-to-one), so probably should be discarded, depending on what you want.

If you make $a$ very big, you converge towards linear mapping $y=x$.

An image showing a few samples:

[image]

Comment: Great mathematical explanation. I can't upvote now but I will.
Thank you for your answer.

Here is the final equation :
$y(x)=(\frac12+\frac12\left(\frac{((2x/255)-1)^3+a(2x-1)}{1+a}\right))*255$

Comment: Accepted as answer as it is the most mathematically correct answer and computer-friendly (no big figures).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lulu, I've found a good solution to my problem.
Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com)

First, here is what I was expecting as the result function :
[image: Original schema]

But to determine a cubic function equation, you need a 4th parameter.
I did the hypothesis that $f(64) ~= 115$.

So I've searched for `InterpolatingPolynomial[(0,0),(255,255),(255/2,128),(64,115)]` in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) which outputed the following schema :
[image: Schema for hypothesis f(64) = 115]

It was a pretty good result. But I wanted that $f(127)>=f(128)>=f(129)$.

So, advised by @lulu, I've tried `InterpolatingPolynomial[(0,0),(255,255),(255/2,128),(64,110)]`.

And it outputed a satisfying result !

[image: Schema for hypothesis f(64) = 110]

Here is by consequence the final savage equation :
$\frac{577744073*x}{197937120} - \frac{1136315963*x^2}{50473965600}+\frac{1483351*x^3}{25236982800}$.

Or for those who want it to computer programs :
`(577744073*x)/197937120 - (1136315963*(x^2))/50473965600 + (1483351 *(x^3))/25236982800`.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(0)=0$, let us consider the cubic equation
$$f(x)=a x+b x^2+c x^3$$
So 
$$f(255)=255 a+ (255)^2 b+(255)^3c$$
$$f\left(\frac{255}{2}\right)=a\left(\frac{255}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{255}{2}\right)^2b+\left(\frac{255}{2}\right)^3c$$
Solve for $a$ and $b$ to get
$$a=\frac{65025 c}{2}+\frac{257}{255}\qquad \text{and}\qquad b=-\frac{765 c}{2}-\frac{2}{65025}$$

T
Using that
$$f(127)=8128 c+\frac{8290687}{65025}$$
$$f(128)=\frac{8355712}{65025}-8128 c$$
$$f(129)=\frac{935637}{7225}-24381 c$$

So, the inequalities would give a quite narrow range for $c$.